# How can I add delay into this function which i wrote for checking live user availability?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am also having problem with this that it always results into 'Username already taken'. how can i fix this thing? I need that ajax loader animation to run for 4seconds and then give the user any message

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#username").change(function() {
            $("#message").html("<img src='ajax-loader.gif' /> checking...");

            var username = $("#username").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "sign_up.php",
                data: "username=" + username,
                success:function(data) {
                    if(data == 0){
                        $("#message").html("<img src='tick.png' /> Username available");
                    } else {
                        $("#message").html("<img src='cross.png' /> Username already taken");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is error in your ajax call it should be as follow

```
$.ajax({
    url: "sign_up.php",
    data: {'username': username},
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
        if(data == 0) {
            $("#message").html("<img src='tick.png' /> Username available");
        } else {
            $("#message").html("<img src='cross.png' /> Username already taken");
        }
    }
});
```

on sign up page you can access username by `$_POST['username']`

Comment: I think jQuery supported both request format json Or text string So his code should be valid.

Comment: @kuldeep.kamboj, Sam is correct in using the object syntax because jQuery will encode the value for transportation. OP's code will only work if the value doesn't contain any special characters such as `&`, which would break the URL encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout before sending ajax request.

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    // Just Pass
}, 4000);
```

This will ensure that request must be executed after 4 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout function. For example following code  will hide div after 3 seconds

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    //hide a div after 3 seconds
    setTimeout( "jQuery('#div').hide();",3000 );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use the setTimeOut() function, that works like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
      // any script here will execute after 2 seconds
}, 2000);
```

Here the code will execute after 2 seconds.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks :) PtitBen :D I ticked your answer but I came to know that I can give green indicator to only one answer :(

Comment: Oh no worries, glad it helped you anyway ^_^

Answer (score 0):

By using `setTimeout()` within the success function, you can delay your response message. I also changed your data assignment to an object, this is better because jQuery will encode the value for you. If you pass a string of data like in your original code, you are responsible for the encoding and you need to wrap it in `encodeURIComponent()`.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "sign_up.php",
        data: {username : username},
        success:function(data){

            setTimeout(function(){
                var msg = data == 0 ? "<img src='tick.png' /> Username available" : "<img src='cross.png' /> Username already taken";

                $("#message").html(msg);
             }, 4000);
        }
}
```